# C# desktop application, UI popup does not come in front of UI and UI goes blur

Tags: c#, forms, infragistics, popupwindow, ultrawingrid

I added a new form in our application, I have used infragistics components in this form. My problem is that after adding this form popup message (messagebox.show()) does not comes in front of UI. After pressing the alt key it comes in front. For another issue I am having, see image [image]

You can see that my UI becomes clumpsy whenever I move this form on the screen.

> There is button on the UI to save the entries. Code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    CashDataManager.GetInstance().Save(lsModifiedTransactions,ModifiedTransactionEnt‌​ries);                                  lsModifiedTransactions.Clear(); 
    ModifiedTransactionEntries.Clear(); 
    MessageBox.Show("Data Saved", "Information");
}
```

This popup hide behind the form and after pressing alt key it comes in front of the form.

I debuged my code and found that this issue is occurring because of  `band.sortedcolumns.add("columnname")` in grids `initializelayount` method.

I removed sorted columns and it is working fine. Can you tell me what the actual issue is?

Comment: There may be issue in the way you show pop-up. It will be easier to identify if you post some code.

Comment: its better to post ur snippet where u think problem occurs otherwise its not possible to find out the issue..

Comment: Look like your way popup window does not synchronize with the UI thread. You should post some code related to the way popup will help us to figure out the root cause.

Comment: The code is easier to read if you edit the question and add it there.  Looking at the code provided, it may help to know what is happening in the Save method.  Also how is the form showing the MessageBox displayed?

Comment: If you were to comment out the call to the Save method, does the message box show correctly or do you still see the issue with rendering?  If the message box shows correctly you will need to provide details on what happens in the Save method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`form.ShowDialog()`

if this does not work:

`form.ShowDialog(mainFormWhichYouDoNotWantToBeOnTop)`

This should do the trick in any case.

Comment: i cant use form.ShowDialog() because i want to work on all the forms simultaneously. Using form.ShowDialog() only current form remain active.

Comment: Set the TopMost property of the Form to true

Comment: I have set the TopMost property to true, but issue is not resolved.